# How to auto populate data from Zoho crm to Zoho creator

Tags: zoho

I am facing a issue. I have to fetch data from ZOHO crm to ZOHO creator and want to fill zoho creator form with that fetched value. I have used webhook to send data from ZOHO crm to ZOHO creator but it saves crm value in database. But i don't want to save in database. I want that value to be fill in creator form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous response contained the wrong link, so here's an updated explanation:

You can pre-populate a form with default values by passing parameters to the form URL.  The format you should follow is:

```
http://creator.zoho.crom/<user name>/<application name>/#Form:<form name>?<field name>=<default value>&<field name 2>=<value 2>
```

The example given in Zoho's support article is:

```
http://creator.zoho.com/zchelp/employee-manager/#Form:Employee?Employee_ID=1234
```

Here's a link to the Zoho Creator support article explaining how to pass parameters into the URL to pre-popluate the form fields with values:

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/url-pattern/functionality-based-urls.html#To_set_default_values_for_form_fields

In the CRM I manage, I added a link into each Zoho CRM record so that when you click it, it will open your Creator form in a new tab and fill it in with the CRM record data. I could set something up like this in a few hours; contact me if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to pass data as a parameter from CRM to the creator. then you can create a Button on CRM Records then Open the URL with passing param.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will create OnLoad Workflow in the Form.
Then you will fetch the data from the Module that you want as below.
You have to fetch data from Zoho creator workflow not pushing data from CRM.

```
 Var_name = zoho.crm.getRecordById("write Module name here", write the record id here without String);
```

then lets say you have Fields (Name, Phone Number);
Name = var_name.getJSON("Name") or whatever the API name, check the Module CRM API's names.
Phone_Number = var_name_getJSON("Tele_Number");

This way, onLoad of the form, data will be fetched everytime from CRM to be visible on the Form.
Please if you have any question, don't hesitate to ask me.

Hope this was useful.